# Значення, етимологія та вживання слова "реновація"

Tags: етимологія, значення-слів, терміни, неологізми

Кілька разів зустрічав вживання слова "*реновація*" у контексті ремонту вулиць, будівель, квартир, [автомобілів](http://vuzlib.com.ua/articles/book/31521-Anal%D1%96z_stanu_problemi_renova%EF%BF%BD/1.html).

У словнику [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/) такого слова не знайшов. Вікіпедія, посилаючись на словник [ВТССУМ](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8), дає наступне визначення:

> Реновація —
>
> 1. Економічний процес оновлення елементів основних виробничих фондів, засобів виробництва (машин, обладнання, інструменту), що вибувають
>      внаслідок фізичного (матеріального) спрацьовування та
>      техніко-економічного старіння за рахунок коштів амортизаційного фонду.
> 2. Відновлення структури і вигляду пошкоджених історичних містобудівних споруд, фасадів та інтер'єрів морально і матеріально
>      застарілих будівель.

Цікавить, яке походження цього слова, чи є інші варіанти тлумачення, окрім наведених, та доцільність його вживання у значенні "ремонт" чи "оновлення"?

Comment: Швидше за все з англійської: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/renovation?s=t

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Це слово у вигляді «Renovation» існує в більшості европейських мов ще з середньовічних часів (в італійській, французькій, англійській, німецькій, тощо), тому встановити, з якої саме мови воно було запозичено в українську, є досить проблематичним. В европейські мови воно [потрапило з латини](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=renovation), від слова *renovatio*, «оновлення», яке утворено за допомогою префікса *re-*, «знову», від дієслова *novare*, «робити новим», а це дієслово – від прикметника *novus*, «новий».

Це слово виглядає й звучить як варваризм, не бачу сенса вживати його окрім як економічний термін, тобто в значенні 1, яке ви навели в запитанні.